Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Laravel 11
(root-directory)\public: Failed to open stream: Permission denied.  this error occurred when I tried to upload a pdf file into (root-directory)\public in Laravel 11, this occurs only when I pdf file but when I upload an image file it works normally.  I already gave permission in my window but it still does not work, can anyone help me with this problem?
    public function savePDF($pdf, $path)
    {
    
        // Generate a unique PDF name
        $pdfName = time() . '_' . uniqid() . $pdf->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
        // Store the PDF file
        $pdf->storeAs($path, $pdfName, 'public');
    
        return [
            asset("storage/$path/" . $pdfName),
            $pdfName
        ];
    }    

I tried to gave permission in both public and storage folder, but it still got an error with Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Is storage/$path writable?  Does it exist?

yes I gave all permission.
